# Huawei mapStyle is not applied properly

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

I am trying to add map style to Huawei map for my app. I had made a JSON file for style from Huawei map style editor and use it in setMapStyle method by MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle and passing the JSON file. I used huawei simple map and add some custom style to it. When I first open the app then the default map (simple) is loaded and the custom styles from JSON is not applied, but I go back to the previous screen and again launch the map screen then the style from JSON is properly applied. How to solve the problem for the first time launch?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please do read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn about how to write a good question. Make sure to always include relevant code in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

First you can follow [this development documents](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-map-style-customization-procedure-0000001061781411) all Steps:

`setMapStyle` method by `MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle` and passing the JSON file, this is load the local map.

To fix the problem need to change the cloud load mapstyle , see the above docs's *Step 5*:

Using a custom style after a map is created
Call the `setStyleId` and `previewId` methods in HuaweiMap to use a custom map style.
The sample code is as follows:

```
HuaweiMap hMap;
// Specify a style ID after a map is created.
hMap.setStyleId(String styleId);
// Specify a preview ID after a map is created.
hMap.previewId(String previewId);
```

Using a custom style before a map is created
Call the `styleId` and `previewId` methods in `HuaweiMapOptions` to use a custom map style. If both `styleId` and `previewId` are set, `styleId` takes precedence.
The sample code is as follows:

```
HuaweiMapOptions huaweiMapOptions;
// Specify a style ID before a map is created.
huaweiMapOptions.styleId(String styleId);
// Specify a preview ID before a map is created.
huaweiMapOptions.previewId(String previewId);
```

use method above will change the cloud map for the first time.

Comment: I follow the same instruction. but didn't get the expected result.

Comment: hi@Partho Bhowmick, you can try to clear the HMS Core apk cache. Also could you pls post some of your updated code?

Comment: Hi @shirley we communicate with Huawei Engineering team regarding map style. It is already a known issue from Huawei HQ.